# How to terminate a process running in parent terminal and in "n" child terminals in linux using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, terminal

I am running a python script "./main.py" in a Linux terminal which automatically launches two other terminals and runs two different code in it, I do this by following,

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import rospy
import psutil, sys
import signal

print(os.getpid())
arra = []
arra.append(os.getpid())
for i in range(2):
    if i == 0:     
        p = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '--', 'roslaunch', 'ur5_notebook', 'main_r2_mt.launch', 'gui:=False'])
    if i > 0:
        p = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '--', 'roslaunch', 'ur5_notebook', 'main_r2_mt.launch'])

    arra.append(p.pid)

rospy.sleep(20)
```

Now I also want kill the parent terminal and also all of the child terminal I have launched. I first I gave a shot with sys.exit() i.e.

```
print(os.getpid())
arra = []
arra.append(os.getpid())
for i in range(2):
    if i == 0:     
        p = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '--', 'roslaunch', 'ur5_notebook', 'main_r2_mt.launch', 'gui:=False'], preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)
    if i > 0:
        p = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '--', 'roslaunch', 'ur5_notebook', 'main_r2_mt.launch'], preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)
# rospy.sleep(50)
    arra.append(p.pid)
# print(list(os.getgroups))
rospy.sleep(20)

sys.exit()
```

But this only killed the current/parent terminal, the child terminals were still active

Then I tried to kill individual process id's (PID), which I do by following

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import rospy
import psutil, sys
import signal

print(os.getpid())
arra = []
arra.append(os.getpid())
for i in range(2):
    if i == 0:     
        p = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '--', 'roslaunch', 'ur5_notebook', 'main_r2_mt.launch', 'gui:=False'])
    if i > 0:
        p = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '--', 'roslaunch', 'ur5_notebook', 'main_r2_mt.launch'])

    arra.append(p.pid)

rospy.sleep(20)

for i in reversed(arra):
     print(i)
     os.killpg(i, signal.SIGINT)
```

But still, only the current terminal process gets closed and not the child process. Please provide me an insight into where I could possibly be making a mistake. I want to write a script that closes all the terminals associated with the parent terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You are having issues using your code because `gnome-terminal` sends a request to `gnome-terminal-server` to start a new terminal and then it exits. You can verify this yourself by executing the following code (a slight variation of your code), where `gnome-terminal` is invoked in one process and `xterm` is invoked in another:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import psutil, sys
import signal
import time

print(os.getpid())

arra = []
#arra.append(os.getpid())

for i in range(2):
    if i == 0:     
        p = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '--', 'yes'])
        print ("gt: " + str(p.pid))
    if i > 0:
        p = subprocess.Popen(['xterm', '-hold', 'yes'])
        print("xt: " + str(p.pid))
    arra.append(p.pid)

for i in reversed(arra):
    print("next kill:" + str(i))
    time.sleep(60)
    os.kill(i, signal.SIGTERM)
```

If you invoke `ps -e | grep gnome-terminal` in another shell while the above code executes, you will see that `gnome-terminal` is defunct and therefore you are not able to kill it. On the other hand if you use xterm, for instance, everything works as you expected.

Sample output:

```
gt: 26054
xt: 26055
next kill:26055

-----------------------------

$ ps -e | grep gnome-terminal
26054 pts/2    00:00:00 gnome-terminal <defunct>
```

So an option is to use `xterm` to execute your code or another type of terminal with a similar behavior.